# UISegmentedControl (Swift2) で、他の segmented control も連動させたい

Tags: swift, swift2

ある segmented control をタップしたとき、それに応じて他の segmented control も切り替えたい（表示だけ）のですが、可能でしょうか？　"self.segmentedControlの名前.selectedSegmentIndex = 1" 等を試しましたがダメでした。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「ある segmented control」と「他の segmented control」とは一体どのような関係でしょうか。同じ画面(同一のViewController)内に複数のsegmented controlが存在するのでしょうか、それとも別画面になるのでしょうか。また、「"self.segmentedControlの名前.selectedSegmentIndex = 1" 等を試しましたがダメでした。」と書いておられますが、一体どうダメだったのかをきちんと記述してくださらないと、何がどうダメだったのかわかりません。「コンパイル自体が通らない」「実行時にエラーになる」「エラー等は出ないが、期待と違う結果になる」等々、「ダメ」なコードで構いませんからコードとエラーが出たのならそのエラー情報も質問自体に含めてください。

Comment: Le Pere d'OO さん、お尋ねくださりありがとうございます。

self.xxx.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
または
xxx.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
(xxx は任意のUISegmentedControl名)

をコンパイルしようとすると、その行で止まります。エラーメッセージは以下の通りです:
Value of type ‘(UISegmentedControl)’ -> () has no member ‘selectedSegmentedIndex’

目標は、UISegmentedControl の選択状態の表示を実際にタップせず、コードで切り替えることです。 実際に押されたときの動作をする必要はむしろ不要です (それは必要なら表示を切り替える側に記述すればいいので)。そういう動作をさせられる何らかのコードが書ければいいので、「あるsegmentedcontrolを使って他のsegmentedcontrolを」に拘ったような書き方は不要でした。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 役に立った回答は承認できます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントでいただいた内容も踏まえて結論めいた書き方をさせていただくと、

- `UISegmentedControl`のプロパティ`selectedSegmentedIndex`に整数値を代入する、という方向性は間違っていない。
- `Value of type ‘(UISegmentedControl)’ -> () has no member ‘selectedSegmentedIndex’`というエラーが出るのは、`self.xxx`の宣言の仕方が間違っている可能性が高い。

参考までに動作確認のために作成したViewControllerの全コードを載せておきます。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segementedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let index = sender.tag
        self.segementedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = index
    }

    @IBAction func resetPressed(_: AnyObject) {
        self.segementedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    }
}
```

InterfaceBuilderでUISegmentedControl(segmentを3つにしました)とUIButtonを4つ(その内3つはtagの値を0, 1, 2としてあり、残り1つがreset用)配置し、各`@IBOutlet`, `@IBAction`に接続してあります。これだけのコードで、UISegmentedControlを直接操作せずにボタンを押すだけで、UISegmentedControlが操作できるのを確認しました。

「これで成功するはずだ」と信じてやりなおしてみると、今まで気づかなかったミスに簡単に気がつくこともありますので、ご自分で解決できるように再度見直していただいてもいいでしょうし、よくわからなければ、問題のエラーを再現できるぎりぎりまで余分なコードを削ぎ落とした上で、問題の全コードを質問に追記していただければと思います。(ご自身の質問は編集できるはずです。)

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん
Outlet接続というお答えが答えでした！

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var yyy:String?

    ＠IBOutlet weak var xxxOutlet: UISegmentedControl!

    ＠IBAction func xxx(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {yyy="aaa"}
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {yyy="bbb"}
    }

    ＠IBAction func yyy(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {yyy="ccc"}
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {yyy="ddd"}

        self.xxxOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
}


嬉しいです。ありがとうございました。